# Angularjs 1.3 directive for jquery UI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

Here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7571/

If you play with sortable items and shuffle them around few times, soon you'll see that the underlying array is not in sync with the order of displayed items. Are there any ideas why this could happen? `arraymove` is well tested function, no bug in it.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" id="maindiv">
     Items debug: {{items}}
     <br>
     Items in ng-repeat:
    <div sortable="items">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" style="background:#EEE; margin: 1px">
          {{item}}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('sortable', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var startIndex = -1;
            var coll;
            scope.$watch(attrs.sortable, function(value) {  coll = value; });
            $(element).sortable({
                containment: '#maindiv',
                scroll:false,
                helper:'clone',
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    startIndex = ($(ui.item).index());
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    var newIndex = ($(ui.item).index());
                    $timeout(function() {
                            arraymove(coll, startIndex, newIndex);
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});


app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['test', 'apple', 'banana'];
});
```

Comment: I just found the source of problem, this happens bacause of `track by $index` in  ng-repeat, so the question is now: do i misuse this feature ?

Comment: Are you using the [Angular-UI version](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)?